# Saw this error when I try to Add-Type of the solution dll, after republishing my website "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json"

Tags: c#, powershell, json.net

I made changes and updated my web page after a year. The web page functions and loads fine but when I try to access a sub project DLL using `Add-Type`, it throws the above error. Really confused as to what the issue is. 
Already tried fixing dependencies and everything. Nothing works! I had all that in place before, only after the republish things are not working.

Error is below:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of 
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Comment: Well, is that file present?

Comment: Yes it is present. That's the whole issue. The web page shows fine but when I address the dll in powershell, it does not work

Comment: Deleted the temporary asp.net files created on the server and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys ! Deleting the temporary files created on the server did the trick for me !